# jQuery UI - move droppable in DOM

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm attempting to tie two sortables together through intermediate droppable elements. However, I can't seem to move the draggables within the DOM from inside the droppable.drop event via the usual appendTo method.

The idea is to drag an item from the sortable onto a droppable that shares the same data-tabid attribute with a sortable, and have the item appear in the corresponding sortable. However, the draggable is returned to its place in the original sortable and not moved to the new sortable.

Am I missing something here? Or is there an easier way to achieve this?

HTML:

```
<div class="tab" data-tabid="10">Tab 1</div>
<div class="tab" data-tabid="20">Tab 2</div>

<div class="area" data-tabid="10">
    <div class="widget" data-id="1">Widget 1</div>
    <div class="widget" data-id="2">Widget 2</div>
    <div class="widget" data-id="3">Widget 3</div>
</div>

<div class="area" data-tabid="20">
    <div class="widget" data-id="4">Widget 4</div>
    <div class="widget" data-id="5">Widget 5</div>
    <div class="widget" data-id="6">Widget 6</div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$('.tab').droppable({
    accept: '.widget',
    hoverClass: 'drop-hover',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var widgetid = ui.draggable.data('id');
        var tabid = $(event.target).data('tabid');
        console.log('widgetid: ' + widgetid + '; tabid: ' + tabid);

        var targetarea = $('.area[data-tabid="' + tabid + '"]');
        console.log('put widget:');
        console.log(ui.draggable);
        console.log('in area:');
        console.log(targetarea);

        ui.draggable.appendTo(targetarea);

        console.log('---=== end drop ===---');
    }
});

$('.area').sortable({
    items: '.widget'
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mloffer/u60qvd9n/3/)

Comment: is the goal only to link the 2 sortables? Cause if so you can use connectWith option in your sortables, like this: connectWith: '.area' and you won't need your droppable

Comment: The goal is to have only one sortable shown at any one time. Clicking on the "tabs" controls which is currently shown. So the only way to move widgets between the two is to drop a sortable onto the tab that shares the same tabid with a sortable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the drop event is triggering too soon, after the successful drop attempt is made, so the drop event is detected, but before the drop actually happens.

if you change

```
ui.draggable.appendTo(targetarea);
```

to

```
setTimeout(function() {ui.draggable.appendTo(targetarea);},0);
```

it works